# Wanting to learn programming more in depth

Tags: java, c

I'm finishing my degree this summer with an IT degree. I had to take several coding courses in C++, Java, HTML / CSS and Python. I never went very deep in all of these languages - just enough to get my feet wet. I felt like I learned concepts more than languages which is good. I'm interested in learning more in hopes of self-training to get a developer job.

Can you point me to books, forums, websites etc... I'm not looking to learn a individual language mow in death just a firmer grasp on programming. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really the site for this type of question...

Comment: @SteveP. IIRC it definitely isn't a good question for that site either

Comment: Yeah I didn't know if it was appropriate thought I'd try.

Comment: *"I didn't know if it was appropriate thought I'd try."* - A better strategy would have been to *read the FAQ **FIRST***

Comment: you can google it, this is the best way to do so...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need "purpose". The best way to learn programming is to do it with a purpose in mind. If you don't have ideas for a project on which to learn (if its something useful or sellable all the better), then look around for open source projects you are interested. Dig in and start working on it. Explore github or google code for projects that interest you. Down load and study the code, etc.